# Отдать файл пользователю для скачивания в Yii2

Tags: yii2

Как правильно реализовать отдачу загруженных файлов с сервера пользователю? Файлы хранятся по пути: web\uploads\files\documents.
В проекте реализована загрузка файлов на сервер по данному пути, с выводом имени загруженных файлов в Gridview (поле filename). Необходимо реализовать отдачу этих файлов пользователю.
Подскажите, как лучше всего это реализовать, если есть пример кода.

Модель:

```
class Documents extends ActiveRecord
```

{

```
public $file;

public static function tableName(): string
{
    return 'documents';
}


public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        [['name', 'forms' ], 'required'],
        [['filename'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['file'], 'file'],


        ];

}



public function attributeLabels(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => 'Имя документа',
        'description' => 'Описание',
        'created_at' => 'Создано',
        'updated_at' =>'Изменено',
        'file' => 'Загрузите файл',
        'filename' => 'Файл',
        'forms' => 'Форма документа',


    ];
}



public function getAuthor (): ActiveQuery
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class(),['id'=>'user_id']);
}



public function behaviors(): array
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::class,
            'attributes' => [
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
            ],
            // если вместо метки времени UNIX используется datetime:
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],

    ];
}
```

}

котроллер:

```
public function actionSaveRedactorFile($sub='documents'): array
{

    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $dir = Yii::getAlias('@files').'/'.$sub.'/';
        if (!file_exists($dir)){
            FileHelper::createDirectory($dir);
        }
        $result_link = 'uploads/files/'.$sub.'/';
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');
        $model = new DynamicModel(compact('file'));
        $model->addRule('file', 'file')->validate();

        if ($model->hasErrors()) {
            $result = [
                'error' => $model->getFirstError('file')
            ];
        } else {
            $model->file->name = uniqid() .'.'. $model->file->extension;
            if ($model->file->saveAs($dir . $model->file->name)) {
                $result = ['filelink' => $result_link . $model->file->name, 'filename'=>$model->file->name];
            } else {
                $result = [
                    'error' => Yii::t('vova07/imperavi', 'ERROR_CAN_NOT_UPLOAD_FILE')
                ];
            }
        }

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;


        return $result;
    } else {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('Only POST is allowed');
    }
}
```